# JavaScript - How do I print an input inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I already tried many ways to solve this, but it always returns `undefined`. What should I do to solve this issue?

```js
function printThreeFavoriteColours() {
  const colours = [];
  const colorUserFav1 = prompt("type your first favorite color");
  const colorUserFav2 = prompt("now, type your second favorite color");
  const colorUserFav3 = prompt("finally, type your third favorite color");
  
  colours.push = (colorUserFav1, colorUserFav2, colorUserFav3);
  console.log(colours);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it, you just need to remove `=` from your example

```
function printThreeFavoriteColours() {
  const colours = [];
  const colorUserFav1 = prompt("type your first favorite color");
  const colorUserFav2 = prompt("now, type your second favorite color");
  const colorUserFav3 = prompt("finally, type your third favorite color");

  colours.push(colorUserFav1, colorUserFav2, colorUserFav3);
  console.log(colours);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
colors.push( //put whatever you want to be pushed here)
```